# Camera perspective in viewport is different to in render

Tags: rendering, camera

I want my image to look like image 1, but when I render, the result is image 2.
Why is the viewport different to the rendered output?
[image: pic 1]
[image: pic 2]

Comment: Please provide a blend file or a screenshot of the camera settings. These can be found by selecting the camera and opening the camera tab in the properties window

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're zoomed in on the viewport, and can't see the edge of your camera.

In the viewport, use the mousewheel to zoom out until the edge of the camera shows up. Select the camera, and move the camera forward with <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>MMB [image: MMB]</kbd>